# Springboot @Bean NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I was using dependency `spring-boot-starter-security` 2.7.15 . This package used `spring-security-config` 5.7.5 as a dependency which has a CVE. In maven, I upgraded the dependencyManagement for `spring-security-config` 5.7.5 -> 5.7.10. Now, when I start my spring boot and run my tests, I get this error in my SecurityWebFilterChain Bean: `Error creating bean with name 'platformSecurityWebFilterChain' defined in com.x.SecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'platformSecurityWebFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatcher org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PathPattern[])'`

My bean looks like this:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain platformSecurityWebFilterChain(
      ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity,
      JwtAuthorizingFilterProperties jwtAuthorizingFilterProperties) {
    return httpSecurity
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers({redacted})
        .permitAll()
...other stuff
```

clearly, maven is able to find the .pathmatchers. I am just not sure how its not internally able to find pathpattern.

Thanks!

Comment: The part you've redacted from your question will help us explain why you're getting this error. However, you can figure this out pretty quickly by looking at the javadocs for ServerWebExchangeMatchers; they have different signatures.  Even if you get past this, you'll likely encounter other issues, these are often not backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is because of the library version conflict issue which not all of your spring security libraries are in the same version. Guess that it is because you are using `spring-security-web` `5.7.5` and `spring-security-config` `5.7.10` ?

But I don't understand why you need to specifically update `spring-security-config` to `5.7.10` as by default `spring-boot` `2.7.15` (and hence `spring-boot-starter-security` `2.7.15`) should already upgrade the `spring-security` to `5.7.10` in `spring-boot` `2.7.14` (See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.7.14)).

So try to make sure all the spring-security libraries (e.g `spring-security-web`) are in the version `5.7.10` which align with your spring-boot version `2.7.15` should solve your problem.